# question of using resource policy on API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

- If there's a DDOS attack against API Gateway, will those failed calls rejected by resource policy be considered into my bill?
- If those failed calls take bandwidth of API Gateway, and make my other valid calls throttled?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are not billed for unauthorized (rejected) requests.

Regarding throttling, if you are referring to API Gateway Usage Plans, rejected calls should not count towards any usage plan. If you are referring to your account limit of 10,000 requests per second (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html) these rejected calls may count towards your limit (I don't know).